# Python smtpib - sending email to multiple recipients

Tags: python, email

I want to send an email to multiple recipients but i can only seem to get it to word for one. does anybody have any ideas? I have included code below, and also the code i have tried which doesnt work

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

email_user = 'jane@doe.com'
email_password = 'password'
email_send = 'jane@doe.comk' #this works fro single recipient
# have tried but doesn't work: email_send = ['jane@doe.com', 'joe@bloggs.com']

subject = 'Latest FI Prices'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = 'Latest FI Prices Attached'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

filename='FI_Prices.csv'
attachment = open('FI_Prices.csv','rb')

part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)

msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_user,email_password)


server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please try as below:-

```
email_send = "jane@doe.com, joe@bloggs.com"
```

above should work.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP is an "ancient" protocol and I'm sure we would design many features quite differently now.

Regarding your question there are two points I'd like to address:

**1. The message and its envelope**

I won't go into details, there are many fine tutorials out there. You need to put the addresses into the message headers as comma separated strings and comments (usually recipients' full names or nicknames) are allowed here. Example:

```
msg['To'] = '"John Doe" <jdoe@example.com>, "Guess Who" <xy@example.com>'
```

and you need to tell the server whom you want to send that message to. This second list of addresses is another list. The addresses there must be without any comments (names).

```
to_addrs = ["jdoe@example.com", "xy@example.com"]
```

Fortunately you usually want to send to those recipients listed in the message. In that case you can tell the `smtplib` to extract the addresses from the message. See [send_message](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.send_message).

**2. return value**

When a message with multiple addresses is sent, the result can be not only success or failure, but also partial success with some addresses accepted and some rejected. Again, see the docs for details.